# Replace a line with a number if part of it is matches using sed

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I know this is a very simple question and been discussed many times, but I can't understand where I am doing wrong in my command.

I would like to replace the lines which starts with "It" as 99999. Each row starts with several blank spaces.

```
infile.txt
     3
     2
     3
     4
  It is not a number = /home/kayan/data
     3
     5
  It is not a number = /home/kayan/data
     4
     5
```

I used

```
sed -i 's/^I/99999/g' infile.txt
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a try:

```
sed -i 's/^\s*It.*/9999/'
```

Comment: Thank you Kent. This works fine. Can I put a format statement inside this command. Because few data in my new file start with several blanks and few with no blanks..

Comment: @Kayan this line will replace lines which start with zero or more blanks then `It` with `9999` So you don't have to care about how many leading blanks in your lines

Answer (score 3):

Due to starting space, add it to pattern search

```
sed -i 's/^[[:blank:]]*I.*/99999/' infile.txt
```

using the change function

```
sed -i '/^[[:blank:]]*I/ c\
9999' infile.txt
```

keeping starting space

```
sed -i 's/^\([[:blank:]]*\)I.*/\199999/' infile.txt
```

No need of the `g`, there is only 1 change per line possible

Answer (score 2):

What you are replacing there is just the `^I` part, i.e. the first letter. Use `^I.*` instead to match the whole remaining line and it also gets replaced.

Comment: Sorry!! There are also blank spaces from each line. So ^I.*/99999 just added 99999 to each line. It didnot replace anything